# Angular 4: I need to create dynamic routes with translations

Tags: angular, dynamic, routes, internationalization

I am working in a project and I need to create dynamic routes using the browser locale. Right now, I have the following configuration:

- Angular CLI
- RouterModule
- angular-translator (https://github.com/feloy/angular-translator)

I tried to use https://github.com/fulls1z3/ngx-i18n-router to solve my routes problem but I realized that is not compatible with angular-cli. So I have to find another way to have this structure:

- domain.com/en/english-word
- domain.com/es/spanish-word
- domain.com/pt/portuguese-word

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: What causes the incompatibility? If you need more control over webpack etc. you can [`ng eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject).

Comment: https://github.com/fulls1z3/ngx-i18n-router/tree/master/packages/@ngx-i18n-router/core#-workaround-for-ngtoolswebpack You must modify the following file **/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js**

Comment: I suggest using environment variables, mainly if you use AOT ( which is recommended ) and change the routes depends on your compilation project locale

Answer (score 0):

With the [ngx-translation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) package, this is pretty simple. Make sure you load different translations in your router file and translate your routes on the fly.

package.json:

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
...
```

assets/i18n/en.json
assets/i18n/es.json...

```
{
  "home": "home",
  "profile": "profile"
}
...
{
  "home": "home",
  "profile": "perfil"
}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const EN: Routes = [
   { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
   { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
]
const ES: Routes = [
   { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
   { path: 'perfil', component: ProfileComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(EN),
    RouterModule.forRoot(ES)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

html:

```
<a routerLink="/{{ 'home' | translate }}">{{ 'home' | translate }}</a>
<a routerLink="/{{ 'profile' | translate }}">{{ 'profile' | translate }}</a>
```